# URLs in JWT scope

Tags: oauth, openid-connect, identity-management

During a pentest I have found a JWT that seems to be a refresh-token issued by some IAM software.

The scope field in the JWT lists all the applications **as URLs** that this token can be used to obtain access tokens for.

From an attacker perspective this seems like a gold mine especially since:

- being a refresh-token its valid for over a month
- I instantly know what applications I can access with the resulting access tokens

So in short: This usage of URL as opposed to some more generic identifiers "feels wrong" to me. But I don't have enough insight in the standards (OAuth, OIDC?) involved to be sure this can be done differently.

So can this be done differently? Should it? Or is it just me being overly paranoid?

Comment: Scopes do not decide which recipients will accept the access token. `aud` claim decides that. What is the value of `aud`?

Comment: I'll have to double check. But it definitely feels they are using this whole thing all wrong.

Comment: Check if they are enforcing audience claim. Even if they are not, it is optional to enforce if they trust each other and the user. A scope can have a arbitrary name. They are probably naming it that way to identify role-scope mappings.